# How to search all rows in a column for a value using STRING_SPLIT in an UPDATE Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-update

I have one table with a single number in each row and I need to determine if that number is in any row in another table that contains ; separated numbers.

I am currently using loops to go through the table searching the column for each row individually.  As you can imagine, it is painfully slow.

I was hoping I could do something like: `UPDATE [nbr_test] SET [found_flag] = 1 WHERE [nbr] IN ( SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(( SELECT [numlist] FROM [findin] ),';') )`

Surprisingly SSMS doesn't show any syntax errors, but I get the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value..." which makes sense, but is there a way to do something similar without using loops and taking forever?
I am using SQL Server 2019

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [nbr_test] (
    [id]    int identity(1,1),
    [nbr]   varchar(50),
    [found_flag] bit
)

CREATE TABLE [findin] (
    [id]    int identity(1,1),
    [numlist] varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO [nbr_test] VALUES
('12345',0),
('34567',0),
('56789',0)

INSERT INTO [findin] VALUES
('23456;67890'),
('98765;12345;01234'),
('06789'),
('56789')
```

And this is ideally what I'd want:

```
|id|nbr  |found_flag|
|1 |12345|1         |
|2 |34567|0         |
|3 |56789|1         |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STRING_SPLIT()` could only take an expression there (like a `SELECT` statement) if it produces a single result. As soon as there is more than one row in `findin`, this is no longer true. You can instead use `CROSS APPLY` to generate the `IN()` values:

```
UPDATE dbo.[nbr_test] 
  SET [found_flag] = 1 
  WHERE [nbr] IN 
  (
    SELECT s.[value] 
      FROM dbo.[findin] AS f
      CROSS APPLY 
      STRING_SPLIT(f.[numlist], ';') AS s
  );
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X-LOZ5zR)

---

> Is it possible to also get the id from findin? Like `SET found_flag=1, found_id=f.id` ?

Sure, it gets a little more complicated. Here's one (possibly not the most efficient) way:

```
UPDATE n
   SET n.found_flag = 1,
       n.found_id   = sq.id
FROM dbo.[nbr_test] AS n
CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT f.id, s.[value] 
      FROM dbo.[findin] AS f
      CROSS APPLY 
      STRING_SPLIT(f.[numlist], ';') AS s
      WHERE s.[value] = n.nbr
  ) AS sq;
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zkmhdNnN)

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for!  Super fast too!

Comment: Is it possible to also get the id from findin?  Like `SET found_flag=1, found_id=f.id` ?

Comment: @Dizzy49 updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply be overcomplicating this.  Why not just use LIKE?

```
UPDATE T
SET T.found_flag = 1
FROM
  @nbr_test T
INNER JOIN
  @findin F
ON
  -- The number is encapsulated in the list => <NoMatch>;<Match>;<NoMatch>
  F.numlist LIKE '%;' + T.nbr + ';%' 
  -- The number is at the end of the list and therefore has no trailing semicolon => <NoMatch>;<Match> 
  OR F.numlist LIKE '%;' + T.nbr 
  -- The number is at the beginning of the list => <Match>;<NoMatch>
  OR F.numlist LIKE T.nbr + ';%'
  -- The number is the entire list, so there are no semicolons
  OR F.numlist = T.nbr --<Match>
```

Comment: If you think `STRING_SPLIT` overcomplicates it, why do you have four clauses instead of `ON ';' + F.numList + ';' LIKE '%;' + T.nbr + ';%'`?

Comment: IIRC the cost of LIKE is more than STRING_SPLIT.  Also, while not noted in my example, there are several cases where I need to find '12345' and there is '12345' AND '12345-CH', and LIKE would catch both of them.